SQL join query without multiplying results
I've already got 2 select statements that create temp tables for Part A and Part B.

Temp tables




Part A
Location




10001
A


10001
B


10001
C






Part B
Location




10001
Z


10001
Y



I want it then to be able to join distinct matches of Part A with Part B, such that there's no duplication of the possible Locations.

Current results (I don't want every combination):




Part A
Location
Part B
Location




10001
A
10001
Z


10001
A
10001
Y


10001
B
10001
Z


10001
B
10001
Y


10001
C
10001
Z


10001
C
10001
Y




Expected results (only one match for each Part/Location):

Which ones match up in this case do not matter.



Part A
Location
Part B
Location




10001
A
10001
Z


10001
B
10001
Y



OR



Part A
Location
Part B
Location




10001
A
10001
Y


10001
B
10001
Z



OR



Part A
Location
Part B
Location




10001
A
10001
Z


10001
C
10001
Y



OR



Part A
Location
Part B
Location




10001
A
10001
Y


10001
C
10001
Z



OR



Part A
Location
Part B
Location




10001
B
10001
Z


10001
C
10001
Y



OR



Part A
Location
Part B
Location




10001
B
10001
Y


10001
C
10001
Z



Current query with actual data. I'd like to have it match the two highlighted lines on left, with ANY two of the highlighted lines on the right. They will match because the 'WO' for both is '10538989'. We know the two on the left are distinct because they have different locations, and the three on the right are distinct because they have different barcode numbers.


@nbk you know that cross join will duplicate the rows , right ? Which is the contrary what OP is asking

why is location C not included in the desired results

Because there's only 2 available Part Bs to match. I'll edit the 'Expected Results' with more 'OR' options, because it could be matched I guess.

Since everything has "10001", get rid of that column for your Question, it is distracting.

Enumerate rows (in CTEs) then join by both table column and row number.
WITH 
cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY {...}) rn FROM table1
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY {...}) rn FROM table2
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column2 AND t1.rn = t2.rn

Output rows amount will be equal to those in smaller table.

Sorry, it's not quite working as I would like. I've put an image of the SQL query using this enumeration in the original post. (Apologies, not quite sure how to get it embedded within the comment)

@AJSadler Please look carefully at the joining condition! Where is the condition 'Door WO' = 'Frame WO'?

Yes, I did that originally, but doing "ON a.ROWNUM = b.ROWNUM and a.[Door WO] = b.[Frame WO]" returns zero results because the matches that I want to make are on different rows. I'm not sure how the ROW_NUMBER() is going to help, because I don't want arbitrary matches.

@AJSadler Add according PARTITION BY clause into the window definition.

I've had a look at the PARTITION BY clause and it sort of makes sense what it does, but I can't figure out how to get it to fit into the statement that I currently have.

@AJSadler Provide sample data and desired output according to Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3.

I did add the screenshot of the actual query and actual data in the original post.

@AJSadler Now please explain me how I can copy the data from your screenshot on my server and test the query with this data.

Here's the query and table data (from the [iFac].[dbo].[i_facscan] table)
https://pastebin.com/VKMKvMgZ

@AJSadler Believe me - if you are asked to provide the source data (7-10 rows is enough) in the form of CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO and show the desired output for this particular data, then this is really necessary. Even if you don't see the point in it.
